# wp_editor not loading completely

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have posted this question in multiple places, but haven't had any responses so going to try here. I am creating a Wordpress plugin. Part of the plugin loads a dropdown from a database. When an option is selected from the dropdown, a form is loaded from an external page using Javascript. The issue I am having is that when I try to load the wp_editor, it is only partially loaded. It is missing the toolbars. Any help is appreciated.

Here is an image of what I am getting.

[image]

Here is the javascript used to load the page:

```js
function showeditevent(str) {
 var location1 = window.location.href;
 var directoryPath = '<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>';
 //alert(directoryPath);
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtEditevent").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtEditevent").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET",directoryPath+"/events/editevent.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

And here is editevent.php

```html
<script src="../../../wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
<script src="../../../wp-includes/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<?php
 require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
 require_once('../../../wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php');
 //require_once('../../../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php');
 
 global $wpdb;
 
 $id = $_GET["q"];
 
 $sql = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "cmc_events where id=$id");
 
 $title = $sql->title;
 $date = $sql->date;
 $time = $sql->time;
 $info = $sql->info;
 $filename = $sql->filename;
 
 $newdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
?>
 <form name="editevent" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th align="right" valign="top">Title:</th>
   <td><input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th align="right" valign="top">Date:</th>
   <td><input type="date" name="newdate" value="<?php echo $newdate; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th align="right" valign="top">Time:</th>
   <td><input type="time" name="newtime" value="<?php echo $time; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th align="right" valign="top">Information:</th>
   <td>
    <?php
    $content = $info;
    $editor_id = 'info';
    $settings = array(
     'textarea_name' => 'info',
     'textarea_rows' => 10,
     'tinymce' => array(
            'width' => 1000
        )
    );
    
    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
    ?>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="save_edit_event" value="Save Edit"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: I use wp_editor with text_area_rows and id. I thought width was computed. Have you tried this without `'tinymce' => array( 'width' => 1000 )` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it with and without that, still had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you check if the current user can richedit by user_can_richedit() function? WP_Editor will only fully load when users can richedit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The user is an administrator, so that shouldn't be the issue. I did try that, and it loaded the wp_editor, or at least how much it usually does.